# how to check when AV player reach special Seconds in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, seconds

I have an AVPlayer and want to do some thing:

**When the video passes 5 seconds or more, print "OK" and when the current time is less than 5 seconds, print(No).**
I know that I should use observer. But I didn't get the result. 
The code here is working well, but not automatically. 
The code works just during the button action. But I want this code to run automatically.
Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    let currentPlayerItem = Player.currentItem
    let duration = currentPlayerItem?.asset.duration

    let currentTime = Float(self.Player.currentTime().value)


        if currentTime >= 5 {

            print("OK")

        }else if currentTime <= 5 {

            print("NO")
        }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.Player.currentItem, queue: nil, using: { (_) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
            self.Player.play()
        }
    })
```

**As you see, I have observer to play again when the video is finished. I want to use this observer when reaching 5th second of the video.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `play()` add a block that runs after 5 secs. Then check if player is still playing.

```
self.Player.play()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 5.0) {
    // check if player is still playing
    if self.Player.rate != 0 {
        print("OK")
        print("Player reached 5 seconds")
    }
}
```